# Chrome is not reading my JSON code [Flash]

Tags: json, google-chrome, actionscript-3, flash, firefox

I've been working on a project using Flash for a while now, and this issue just cropped up. I'm used to working with using JSON in flash for game projects because I've done it several times in the past, but for some reason it isn't working correctly right now, consistently and it is very confusing.

So, the process is supposed to be like this:

1. The title screen loads.
2. The user presses begin and the game grabs level data from the single JSON file
3. It loads but only shows 1 town and a window telling the player what to do.

It works perfectly in Firefox and internet explorer, it just doesn't work in chrome and I don't know why.

The swf is embedded using object tags and active x for internet explorer.
[Link Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f1d23bade90949aed1dac51023c65a42)

The AS3 code is here. It uses the JSON parser to load the levels.  [Link Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/62a048662f8b9d87e8215f2eee6062d4)

**It should look like this.** It looks like this in firefox, IE and in the debugger. [Link Here](http://share.cherrytree.at/showfile-25428/untitled2.png)

**In chrome it looks like this**. All the missions are unlocked and none of the buttons work. 
[Link Here](http://share.cherrytree.at/showfile-25429/untitled2.png)

Comment: And what gets actually parsed in chrome? What gets stored in all that level arrays? What strings do you get in chrome and firefox as `loader.data`?

Comment: The loader.data should be a JSON string. I don't know how to check it in the browser, once it's run, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I usually add a test `TextField` to the stage and add debug output there

Comment: Accessing local files through the browser is likely a security thing. Different browsers have different policies.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.@www0z0k that was very useful and I found out that it wasn't reading the path (since it technically belonged to a folder that no longer existed) and moving it to the top folder fixed the issue.